# What is the meaning of „dagobertinisch“?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I can not understand the meaning of *dagobertinisch* in the following sentence:

> Wenn demnächst die wohlhabende und kirchlich stark gebundene Generation der Baby-Boomer das Ruhestandsalter erreicht, könnte die dagobertinische Epoche der Kirchengeschichte schlagartig ihr Ende finden, warnen Finanzexperten.

Answer (score 14):

It translates to *Dagobertian* (the adjective to the first name "Dagobert") - just like "Edwardian" denotes the era of "Edward".

This doesn't help you much as a direct translation. You need to take into account that *Scrooge McDuck*, the impersonation of pure immense wealthiness, is called *Dagobert Duck* in the German translation of the Walt Disney comic - The adjective is used here as a tongue-in-cheek description for an era that swept a lot of financial and other support into the churches.

So, a very literal translation of your sentence would be along the lines of

> When soon the wealthy and closely ecclesiastically tied generation of baby boomers will reach pension age, the Scrooge-McDuckian epoch of church history could abruptly come to an end, financial experts warn.

Comment: To give more context: The German Catholic church and its protestant counterpart, the German *Evangelische Landeskirchen* (in their sum) are considered the two richest Christian Church entities worldwide. They own so many businesses in Germany and worldwide it's hard to find a business they don't have their fingers in. (And, this is the reason why those *Finanzexperten* aren't worth a single penny.)

Comment: https://www.welt.de/vermischtes/article13679586/Katholische-Kirche-macht-mit-Pornos-ein-Vermoegen.html

Comment: Here is a [quote for a deeper explanation](https://books.google.de/books?id=-qNm65gXZLUC&lpg=PA119&ots=BRoBhSuY84&dq=hauschild%20dagobertinisch&pg=PA119#v=onepage&q=hauschild%20dagobertinisch&f=false). The term *dagobertinisch* was introduced by [Hauschild](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolf-Dieter_Hauschild_(Theologe))